# Attaching another table after a hasManyThrough relationship

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to connect 4 tables together:

```
StepAnimation Model:
    public function steps()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Step','App\Models\WorkSequence');
    }
    public function step()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Step');
    }


Step Model:
    public function workSequence()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\WorkSequence');
    }
    public function stepAnimation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\StepAnimation');
    }

WorkSequence Model:
    public function categoryWorkSequence()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CategoryWorkSequence');
    }
    public function step()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Step');
    }

CategoryWorkSequence Model:
    public function workSequence()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\WorkSequence');
    }
```

I am currently selecting all the work sequences that have a step animation:

```
$this->stepAnimation = New StepAnimation();
$workSequence = $this->stepAnimation::with('step.workSequence')->get();
```

But now id like to attach all the categories to the worksequence, how do i need to extend the select for that to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can continue selecting the category relationship in your workSequence as long as it is available on your model. Like this.

```
$this->stepAnimation = New StepAnimation();
$workSequence = $this->stepAnimation::with('step.workSequence.categoryWorkSequence')->get();
```